# imap_delete deleting without imap_expunge being called

Tags: php, imap

The concept is I want to get emails from my gmail account and upload them into a database. Then delete the messages afterwards, I've got it all working however sometimes I want to keep the messages in the gmail after uploading so I manually comment out the line imap_expunge but then it still deletes the messages.
For example :

```
$mbox = imap_open('{'.$mail_server.':'.$mail_port.$mail_certificate.'}'.$mail_folder, $mail_username, $mail_password) or die('Error opening mailbox: <br /> '.imap_last_error());

foreach ($mailboxheaders as $val) {
      $msgno++;
      $msgType = checkMsgType($mbox, $msgno);
      if($msgType === "RS-StaffJourno"){
           staffJournoMsg($mbox, $msgno);
      }
}

//imap_expunge($mbox);
imap_close($mbox);

function staffJournoMsg($mbox, $msgno){
    $type = "Journo";       
    setVars($mbox, $msgno, $type);
    imap_delete($mbox, $msgno);
}
```

The setVars() works fine. My problem is even when commented imap_expunge is commented out the script still deletes the messages that are marked.

When I comment out the imap_delete() it doesn't delete the messages but I would rather comment out one line instead imap_delete on every kind of message type. I've tried looking into this but I can't find anyone else who has had this kind of problem.

This is just a snippet of the code I am using and everything works fine but is there some way that imap_delete() is deleting the messages instead of just marking them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gmail IMAP server has a non-standard feature: it deletes messages as soon as they're marked `\Deleted`, without waiting for an `EXPUNGE` command:

```
C: 377 UID STORE 52372 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
S: * 6247 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted) MODSEQ (6219134) UID 52372)
S: * 6247 EXPUNGE
S: * 6248 EXISTS
S: 377 OK Success
```

So when you're connecting to the Gmail server, the only way not to delete messages is not to call `imap_delete`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know gmail had this feature. Looks like its the long way of doing things for me:)